# Vertical axis not aligning to the left

Tags: telerik, nativescript

I've a NativeScript RadCartesianChart with a DateTimeContinuousAxis. By using the DateTimeContinuousAxis the content of the chart doesn't seem to align to the left, instead it has some space between the horizontal axis and the content.

How can I align the content to the left?

```
<RadCartesianChart tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
    <RadCartesianChartGrid tkCartesianGrid horizontalLinesVisible="true" horizontalStripLinesVisible="true"
        horizontalStrokeColor="#E5E5E5" horizontalStrokeWidth="1" horizontalStripLineColor="#ffffff, #ffffff">
    </RadCartesianChartGrid>
    <LinearAxis lineHidden="true" labelMargin="25" tkCartesianVerticalAxis></LinearAxis>
    <DateTimeContinuousAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis majorStep="2" majorStepUnit="Hour" dateFormat="HH:mm"
        labelFitMode="Rotate" labelRotationAngle="1.2">
    </DateTimeContinuousAxis>
    <Palette tkCartesianPalette>
        <PaletteEntry tkCartesianPaletteEntry fillColor="#AFD9FD" strokeColor="#54AFFB"></PaletteEntry>
    </Palette>
    <SplineAreaSeries tkCartesianSeries legendTitle="Prijzen" [items]="priceSource" categoryProperty="applyDate"
        valueProperty="price">
    </SplineAreaSeries>
</RadCartesianChart>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it iOS or Android?

Comment: @Manoj It's android.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue, can you share a Playground sample.